# Given a unitary vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$ and a vector $y=(x_2,\ldots, x_n)^T$, prove the columns of a created matrix form an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, unitary-matrices

> Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}\in M_{n1}(\Bbb F),x_1\ne-1$ be a unit vector wrt the standard scalar product and let $Y=\begin{bmatrix}x_2\\x_3\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}\in M_{n-1,1}(\Bbb F).$
>
> Prove that the columns of the matrix $$M=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y^*\\y&\frac1{1+x_1}yy^*-I\end{bmatrix}$$ form an orthonormal basis for $M_{n1}(\Bbb F)$
>
> Note: $y^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $y$.

This is what I tried:

I would like to prove the given
matrix $M$ is unitary by showing $MM^*=I$.
First, I wanted to analyse the Hermitian matrix $$yy^*=\begin{bmatrix}x_2\bar x_2&x_2\bar x_3&\ldots&x_2\bar x_n\\x_3\bar x_2&x_3\bar x_3&\ldots &x_3\bar x_n\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\x_n\bar x_2&x_n\bar x_3&\ldots&x_n\bar x_n\end{bmatrix}$$
We can see that $\operatorname{rank}(yy^*)=1\implies\operatorname{Ker}(yy^*)=n-1$.

Furthermore, $$yy^*y=y(y^*y)=\|y\|^2y,$$

which means $y$ is an eigenvector of the matrix $yy^*$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\|y\|^2=1-|x_1|^2=1-x_1\bar x_1$ since $\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2}=1$, and we conclude $\sigma(yy^*)=\{0,1-x_1\bar x_1\}$.

If $x_1\in\Bbb R, M=M^*,$ but it can happen that $x_1\not\in\Bbb R$.

I tried writing: $$\left(\frac1{1+x_1}yy^*-I\right)y=\begin{bmatrix}\left(\frac{1-x_1\bar x_1}{1+x_1}-1\right)x_2\\\left(\frac{1-x_1\bar x_1}{1+x_1}-1\right)x_3\\\vdots\\\left(\frac{1-x_1\bar x_1}{1+x_1}-1\right)x_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1+\bar x_1}{1+x_1}x_1x_2\\-\frac{1+\bar x_1}{1+x_1}x_1x_3\\\vdots\\-\frac{1+\bar x_1}{1+x_1}x_1x_n\end{bmatrix}$$
but it wasn't quite helpful.

How should I proceede?

Thank you very much for your time and patience!

Comment: I don't know how helpful it is, but this transformation looks very similar to the [Householder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) transform.

Comment: Is this true? I don't get $M$ unitary when $X = [1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: @YipJungHon,for $x=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt 2}\\\frac1{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix},$ I get $$y=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix},\\\frac1{1+x_1}yy^*-I=\frac1{1+\frac1{\sqrt 2}}\frac12-1=\frac1{2+\sqrt 2}-1=\frac{1-2-\sqrt 2}{2+\sqrt 2}=-\frac{1+\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2(1+\sqrt 2)}=-\frac1{\sqrt 2}$$ and $$M=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt 2}&\frac1{\sqrt 2}\\\frac1{\sqrt 2}&-\frac1{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Should your matrix $\ M\ $ be given instead by
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
|x_1|&y^*\\
y&\frac{1}{1+|x_1|}yy^*-I
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
$$
which is unitary?  As you've given it, it's only unitary when $\ x_1\ $ is real.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, this is how, unfortunately, the problem was formulated, I checked it once again just in case, but, it may be as you say, some typefeller. Counter-examples are more than welcome if the task is flawed. I apologise for the low-quality.

Comment: Sorry @Dolphin, my bad, I didn't bother simplifying the expression

Comment: Counterexamples are tedious to find for the reason that for this statement to be false, $x_1$ must not be fully imaginary or real. Consider $$(1+x_1)M = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\left(1+x_1\right)&\bar{x_2}\left(1+x_1\right)\\ x_2\left(1+x_1\right)&x_2\bar{x_2}\:-\:1-\:x_1\end{pmatrix}.$$ When I do the inner product between the first and second column, I get $x_1(1+x_1) x_2(1+\bar{x_1}) + x_2(1+x_1)(x_2\bar{x_2} - 1 - \bar{x_1})$, which reduces down to $(1+x_1)(x_2)(x_1 - \bar{x_1})$. If $x_1$ were fully imaginary or real, $x_1 - \bar{x_1}$ would be $0$.

Comment: Which is why I believe this statement should be false despite not having an explicit counterexample. Counterexamples shouldn't be hard to find though, just choose some $x_1$ which is neither fully imaginary or real, find an $x_2$ such that the norm of $x$ is $1$, and do the necessary manipulation to see that the inner product of columns $1$ and $2$ is $x_1 - \bar{x_1}$ and not $0$.

Comment: What I asserted earlier is not quite true.  If $\  x_ 1=\pm i\ $ and $\ Y=0\ $ then $\ M\ $ will be unitary.  However, I believe these are the only cases of a non-real $\ x_1\ $ for which $\ M\ $ will be unitary.  I strongly suspect that whoever set the problem was assuming $\ x_1\ $ to be real when they calculated $\ MM^*\ $.

Comment: Yes, except that I calculated $\ M^*M\ $ rather than $\ MM^*\ $, but since they're just conjugate transposes of each other, the difference is immaterial.  If $\ y\ne0\ $ then
$$
MM^*=\begin{bmatrix}
1&\Big(\frac{2i\mathfrak{Im}(x_1)}{1+\overline{x}_1}\Big)y^*\\
\Big(-\frac{2i\mathfrak{Im}(x_1)}{1+x_1}\Big)y&I
\end{bmatrix}\  ,
$$ so $\ M\ $ is unitary if and only if $\ x_1\ $ is real.  If $\ y=0 \ $, then the entry in the first row and column of $\ MM^*\ $ is $\ |x_1|^2\ $, which is $1$ if and only if $\ x_1=\pm1\ $ or $\ x_1=\pm i\ $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given, $\ M\ $ is not always unitary.  Take
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
then
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{2+i\sqrt{2}}-1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1+i\sqrt{2}}{2+i\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\begin{align}
MM^*&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1+i\sqrt{2}}{2+i\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{i\sqrt{2}-1}{2-i\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{i}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{2}-1}{2\sqrt{2}-2i}\\
\frac{-i}{2}-\frac{1+i\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}+2i}&1
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{2\sqrt{2}i}{2\sqrt{2}-2i}\\
\frac{-2\sqrt{2}i}{2\sqrt{2}+2i}&1
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{-\sqrt{2}+2i}{3}\\
\frac{-\sqrt{2}-2i}{3}&1
\end{bmatrix}\ .
\end{align}